# SAMLRequest hidden in subsamples and is used in redirect in the same main sample

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing

I have recorded a website where there are 2 identity providers, the first checks AD Groups, the second is the normal UserId and DoB. In the recording I have added an authorisation manager for the first identity provider request.

When I re-run the recording , the very first sampler uses SAML request , and if I look into the tree view , I can see the SAML request is generated in subsample which is then used in the redirect.

I am not sure how to capture that SAML request as it is the same sub sample redirects.

Or if there is a different way to handle this?

Answer (score 0):

JMeter [Post-Processors](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#postprocessors) like [Regular Expression Extractor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Regular_Expression_Extractor) or [Boundary Extractor](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-boundary-extractor) have "Apply to" parameter:

[image]

so if the value you need to extract is in a sub-sample - you should configure the Post-Processor to look into `Sub-samples only`